# 5.8 Liter E350 1996 Ford pressure feedback sensor

Tags: repair

Where is the pressure feedback sensor on my 1995 Ford E350. I am getting an EGR code and have replaced the EGR valve, the position sensor, the Control Solenoid and last to replace is the pressure feedback sensor. I can't find it... please help

Answer (score 0):

If you've already replaced the EGR valve then you just need to follow the hose running out of that towards the drivers side of the engine bay. The pressure feedback sensor will be at the end of that hose fastened to the engine bay wall.